# What does the line " get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient' " do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning ruby on rails and I am having trouble understanding the line:

Excerpt from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

What does the single colon in the context of the string literal mean? I think the 'get' function parses it.
What about the single colon in the context of the 'to' and 'as'? Of this, I haven't a clue.

I read that single colon refers to a symbol, but they always appear in following format format
:nospace_varname

In essence, this is a syntax question.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In recent versions of Ruby, `x: a` is shorthand for `:x => a`. So `to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'` is shorthand for `:to => 'patients#show', :as => 'patient'`. It's a hash.

Comment: Hey, it turns out that you're question was a little confusing, because people either thought you were talking about the colon inside of the string, or the colons used as part of the hash parameters. You might want to clarify what you were actually confused about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following definition

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'
```

generates a route as:

```
 patient GET    /patients/:id(.:format)              patients#show
```

where

`get` : Refers to the HTTP method

`/patients/:id` : will be the route that is matched like `/patients/1`. **`:id` is just a placeholder.**

`to: 'patients#show'` : will map the route to `show` action of `PatientsController`

`as: 'patient'` : will create a `prefix` for your route. So, you can easily access it within application as `patient_url` or `patient_path`.

When you access this path as `patient_path(@patient)` where @patient is an instance of Patient record with id=1. Then the route generated would be `/patients/1`. **:id** would be mapped with the `@patient.id`.

As far the colon in `to:` and `as:` goes, they are required as these are the options passed in get method. They are passed as a Hash and as per Ruby syntax for hash, if key is a **symbol** then    `:` would be required to denote it as **symbol**.

It could be used either way, with new Ruby(Ruby 1.9 and up) syntax as:

```
to: 'patients#show'
```

or with old Ruby syntax as:

```
:to => 'patients#show'   ## Using Hash Rocket
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew what it was doing conceptually, the syntax threw me off.

Comment: The original poster was confused about the hash syntax, not so much with the `get` method itself.

Comment: @Cupcake I explained in detail what each part is for including `:id`. Look at the question title `What does the line “ get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient' ” do?` Thats why I explained each part.

Comment: @KirtiThorat my bad, you're right, the question was confusing.

Comment: @Cupcake No Problem!! As long as we are on same path :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternate syntax.

```
get('/patients/:id', { :to => 'patients#show', :as => 'patient' })
```

get is a method call. The first argument is a String. The second argument is a Hash

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know even the arrows were not necessary. Will accept later.

Comment: @user2316667 keep in mind that it depends on your version of Ruby. Older versions will not have this shortcut syntax available.

Comment: So it turns out that the original poster was talking about ***this*** colon: `'/patients/:id'`. It was a little confusing though, I thought he was talking about hash parameters too.

Comment: Oh boy, actually, turns out the OP was asking about both! My bad :/

Answer (score 2):

> What does the single colon in the context of the string literal mean? I think the 'get' function parses it.

This is a rails convention for naming query parameters. As for how routing works in rails, you should read the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

> What about the single colon in the context of the 'to' and 'as'? Of this, I haven't a clue.

This is a ruby syntax for hashes. For more info, see the [Ruby Hash docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html)

```
hash = foo: "bar", hello: "world"
# {foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
```

Comment: So it turns out that the original poster was talking about ***this*** colon: `'/patients/:id'`. It was a little confusing though, I thought he was talking about hash parameters too.

Comment: Oh boy, actually, turns out the OP was asking about both! My bad :/

Comment: I thought I answered both, though... `v.v`

Comment: Sorry, not enough coffee this morning :/

Answer (score 1):

The colon in the `get '/patients/:id'` is simply a placeholder and refers to the property of the `Patient` object which will be placed there in your URL to identify the patient to be requested. So when you are redirecting to the `patient_path` with a patient `id` value of 5, you would get this URL: `yourpage.com/patients/5`.

The next part is indeed a `Hash`. The `to` part says that the `show` method within the `patients`(controller) will be called for execution. The `as` part is simply an alias so you have better access to the path from your code. If you call it `'somepatient'`, you can access it using the `somepatient_path` helper.

The colons from those two values simply stem from the hash. It is an alternative syntax to the (older) `to => 'patient#show', as => 'patient'`, while the surrounding curly braces used for hashes can be omitted in this case because the hash is the final argument of the call, otherwise it could be ambiguous.